# Transition method when there is one uitableview on one uicollectionview cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

There is one uitableview above one uicollectionviewcell.
Even if you tap this uitableview cell, it will not transit.

The protocol is as follows.

```
class (the name of this collectionViewCell): UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {...
```

In order to make a transition,
Since there is a `UIViewController` underlying `collectionViewCell`,
I wanted to use that `navigationController`.

I did the following code in `didSelectRowAt` indexPath:

```
uiVC = UIViewController()
self.uiVC? .navigationController?. pushViewController(DummyViewController(), animated: true)
```

However, it can not make a transition.
Is the transition method incorrect?
Please let me know if you know one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your uiVC doesn't have UINavigationController.

```
uiVC = UIViewController()
self.uiVC? .navigationController?. pushViewController (DummyViewController(), animated: true)
```

Write a code at awakeFromNib:

```
 uiVC = UIViewController()
 var navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: uiVC)
 self.addSubview(navigationController.view)
 // TODO: add constraints
```

Than you'll see transition.

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not use a storyboard.

Comment: How can I write in override init?